# Sized integers and promotions in varargs functions

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Sized integers (those from stdint.h) are actually typedefs to standard C types. So, the "default arguments promotions" that apply in variadic (varargs) functions such as printf() will be applied to them as well, so that char and short are cast to int (signed or unsigned).

I'm writing a printf-like function that is designed for sized integers. It has a format string that has the size information for all the integers in the variable argument list.

How should I write the varargs querying code, so that it retrieves each argument with its correct size? I guess my function will need to be aware of default argument promotions, but they are compiler/system-dependent, because it depends on whether the system has a 16/32/64 bit int. How can I get the arguments right, in a compiler-independent way?

Comment: "How can I get the arguments right, in a compiler-independent way?" well, no way other than from the platform documentation you're provided.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is - isn't that what `va_arg` is for?

Comment: What is the problem in using `va_arg`?

Comment: Actually, I think I understand.  You're saying that you can't safely do (for example) `va_arg(ap, int16_t)`, because you don't know if `int16_t` is an `int` or a `short` (and thus whether it would have been promoted or not).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth somehow I wishfully expect that there would be a #define or #pragma for that :) good catch.

Comment: It would be nice if the stdarg interface were aware of argument promotions and automatically repackaged them to the desired type, but that's not the case, so you need to know how arguments are promoted, use the promoted types when extracting the arguments, then cast them back down to the original types as needed.  So while the clients may be portable, the library that supports this probably won't be.

Comment: Well, my idea was to make my function guess the promotions by comparing the sizeof() standard C types vs the sizeof() sized integers, but I'm not sure if such approach would be failsafe.

Comment: @cesss: Yes, I guess you could do `#if (sizeof(int16_t) < sizeof(int)) int16_t x = va_arg(ap, int); #else int16_t x = va_arg(ap, int16_t); #endif` and so on.

Comment: "It has a format string that has the size information for all the integers in the variable argument list." is a bit problematic.  Better to have _type_ information for all the integers in the variable argument list.

Comment: @Shark Does [PromoType(v)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36266215/2410359) grant your wish?

Comment: An example usage of "printf-like function" would help.

Comment: @chux yes it does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine if `some type` becomes `int`, `unsigned` or stays the same type when passed to a function with `...`, code could use `_Generic()`.   (C99 or later)

By using `*1`, this mimics the usual promotions seen with `f(format, ...)`.

Now your *printf-like function* can determine if the argument was promoted to `int`, `unsigned` or left as-is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PromoType(v) _Generic(v*1, \
  unsigned : "unsigned", \
  int : "int", \
  default: "no change" \
  )

int main(void) {
  int16_t i16;
  puts(PromoType(i16));
  uint16_t u16;
  puts(PromoType(u16));
  int32_t i32;
  puts(PromoType(i32));
  uint32_t u32;
  puts(PromoType(u32));
  int64_t i64;
  puts(PromoType(i64));
  uint64_t u64;
  puts(PromoType(u64));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
int
int
int
unsigned
no change
no change
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, chux. This solves my question. Anyway, I'll write several code paths, because from time to time I need to build my code with older compilers which may not support C99. I found the typeof GCC extension, which can be an alternative to this. And in case the compiler doesn't support C99 and isn't GCC either, I'll use the sizeof() approach suggested by Oliver Charlesworth above. Thanks!